# Como alterar o formatNoMatches no select2 4.0.0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Estou utilizando o **select2 4.0.0** e estou com problemas na hora de alterar a forma como é mostrado a mensagem que indica não ter encontrado resultados. Na versão antiga utilizava `formatNoMatches` para alterar a apresentação, como é feito agora?
obs: não posso alterar isso direto no arquivo *pt-BR.js* porque cada `select` tem um comportamento diferente.

```
$('#id_categoria').select2(
    {
        placeholder:'Selecione',
        minimumInputLength: 2, 
        formatNoMatches: function(term) {
            return "Nenhum resultado. Adicionar " + term + "?";
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que o jeito padrão de fazer isso na versão 4 é pelo arquivo de linguagem.

Entretanto eu fucei um pouco e acabei desenvolvendo um *work-around* que funciona:

```js
$(function() {
  var id_categoria = $('#id_categoria')
    .select2({
      placeholder: 'Selecione',
      minimumInputLength: 2,
      language: $.extend({},
        $.fn.select2.defaults.defaults.language, {
          noResults: function() {
            var term = id_categoria
              .data('select2')
              .$dropdown.find("input[type='search']")
              .val();

            return $("<span>Nenhum resultado. <span class='add'>Adicionar <b>" + term + "</b></span>?</span>");
          }
        })
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0-rc.2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0-rc.2/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="js-example-responsive" id="id_categoria" style="width: 50%">
</select>
```

Eu sei que não é muito bonito, mas só assim consegui definir o texto, dinamicamente para o select.

Comment: Isso realmente funciona, no entanto não está retornando código HTML, sabe como resolver isso? A ideia seria retornar um `return "Nenhum resultado. <span class='add'>Adicionar <b>" + term + "</b></span>?";`

Comment: Editei a resposta para retornar HTML... basta retornar um objeto jQuery: `$("<span>what ever</span>")`

Comment: @Orion sua ideia é retornar o "term" para posteriormente envia-lo em post para salvar né ?

Comment: @Rod exato, ao clicar em adicionar irei pegar o `term` e salvar via Ajax, alem de adicionar ao `select`.

Comment: @Orion e aonde você irá deixar o button para mandar o post? rs (Também estou precisando de algo assim kk)

Comment: @MiguelAngelo eu abri uma questão no repositório do select2 para ver se existe uma solução mais simples para isso, eu havia buscado mas não encontrei nada na documentação. O certo era ter uma opção de fazer isso por padrão.

Comment: @Rod ao clicar no `span` eu vou pegar o texto digitado e adicionar ao `select`.